# Why is my application getting more CPU usage while it's halting the operation

Tags: windows

I have a question about the way OS gives CPU time to the applications. Usually when I render my scene with a single object in it I get ~8% CPU usage, but when I stop the framework for further process while my window has lost focus I see that my application has a ~50% CPU usage. Now, I'm a little bit confused about this behavior because supposedly I should get no CPU time at all.

The pseudo code is something like this:

```
while(open)
{
  // Window
  window->update();

  // Freeze when we have no focus
  if (freeze) continue;

  // Physics, Input, Render ...
  do_the_stuff();
}
```

The situation that I'm talking about is when I set `freeze` to true and just process the window messages. It means there is only one job to do per frame.

Comment: I don't see where you "halt" the thread to let it sleep.  In your pseudo-code, the thread is always going, and would therefore have pegged a full core at 100% usage.

Comment: @TrevorPowell Well I was thinking if I simply skip the loop, I'll get no more process time. So I should put the thread to sleep before skipping the loop? A code example might be good.

Comment: `continue` doesn't "skip" the loop -- it starts the loop again, right this very moment.  You're still executing the 'while' loop.

Comment: @TrevorPowell By "skip" I meant not running the rest of the loop, but thanks for your help anyway, I realized how I should be doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop you probably have vsync on, or other stuff like "wait for input" that limits your cpu usage because the program has to wait for other tasks.
When you "freeze" your application it becomes just an infinite loop.
If you launch the following program

```
int main()
{
    while(true);
    return 0;
}
```

of course it won't terminate, and its cpu usage will be 100%.
You probably have 50% because your system is a dual core pc. You'll get 25% with a quad core, because it isn't a multithreading application.

I haven't tried it but probably if you launch another expensive program it will have a higher priority than yours in background that will reduce its cpu usage.
I think the OS tries to use as many cpu's resource as it can. All the "normal" application (no game or programs like WinRAR) usually wait for user's input or they have a sleep() function inside them, so they can't have a lot of cpu usage. The only program remaining is yours, so it goes at 100%.

I think you can't put the thread to sleep because it won't know when it has to wake up.
Sleep simply tells the OS not to schedule the program for the time passed in the barracks.
A sleep(1000) means that the program will stop for a second even if, in the meanwhile, it acquires focus.
A solution is:

```
if(freeze)
{
    sleep(100);
    continue;
}
```

if you use higher number you'll get a little delay after you click on the application and before it starts.

Comment: Actually I solved my problem by the help of the above comments. At that time I wrote exactly the solution you're providing and it worked fine. I wasn't paying attention to the infinite loop at first so I became a little bit confused, and yes, I have a dual core CPU. Thanks anyway.